# MySQL: the SET Type

Tags: mysql, set

I am learning about "(MySQL) - SET Type", At the Mysql, I didn't understand the following statement:
The Link: [The SET Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html).

> MySQL stores SET values numerically, with the low-order bit of the
>   stored value corresponding to the first set member. If you retrieve a
>   SET value in a numeric context, the value retrieved has bits set
>   corresponding to the set members that make up the column value.

As they saying "numerically" i understand that "Behind the scenes" there is 2 columns, 1 With the SET members and 1 with the numeric values following by the binary system(1,2,4,8,16,etc..).

Also i didn't get this statment:

> If a number is stored into a SET column, the bits that are set in the
>   binary representation of the number determine the set members in the
>   column value. For a column specified as SET('a','b','c','d'), the
>   members have the following decimal and binary values.

The big picture I do not understand under what values the SET members stored in the database and would be very happy if some one may help me, Thank you all and nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SET data type values are stored as integer numbers, and SET values ('val1', 'val2'...) are stored in bits; 64 values are possible - 8 bytes integer number.

There is an article about the SET type and its using - [How to edit values of SET data type](http://buysql.com/mysql/55-edit-set-type-values.html).